# Update Dispatch model with child model utterances

Tags: botframework

What is the right way to add the `utterances` in the `Dispatch LUIS` model, say I have two child `LUIS models` A & B inside my parent `Dispatch LUIS` Model.

Now, I added an utterance in the `LUIS` model A how to update the same utterance in `Dispatch` model. I am adding it manually right now , but I think there must be a better way of doing this. I tried googling it but didn't end anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

You have to do this through the CLI via the command `dispatch refresh`. A complete list of commands and options can be found on the [Dispatch Tool Github page](https://github.com/Microsoft/botbuilder-tools/tree/master/packages/Dispatch).

Comment: Dispatch refresh doesn't help. Can you guide me better. Where exactly should we add the utterances for the child models in the LUIS portal or in the text file that is created in the CognitiveModels folder ?

Comment: Also, the utterances which i have added on the LUIS portal, I don't see them syncing even after running the dispatch refresh.

Comment: Unfortunately I'm not sure, then. I'm not sure why refresh wouldn't work.